# R or spss? For a conditional regression with 2 dependent variables?

Tags: conditional-probability, resampling, regression-strategies, case-control-study, gwas

Maybe you find my question a bit simple but I'm really confused as I'm not statistician.

I have 2 SNPs (can be proposed 2 genes instead) that are related to a primary disease (like major depression), by simple cross sectional case-control design.

already it is clarified there is a significant correlation between these two SNPs and the primary disease by a simple linear regression.

There is an interest to find out the relationship between these two SNPs (which are corelated to the primary disease) and a secondary trait (like low working memory) in a resampling manner. To reach the answer I tried to got a lot around the topic. First I had to know if it needs probability formulas or statistics as the data are collected in a cross sectional way.

1)after all I've reached to Conditional Logestic Regression, I need to know if I got true?

2) Chen et Al [2013] suggested a formula 
[image: logistic regression by chen et al]
In a way that (D) is primary disease and (Y) is the secondary trait, (G) should be SNP I guess and (E) is environment factor. So if it is the exact formula for my question, how it can be done in R or SPSS?

3) additionally for the primary disease (Major depression) sample size is aboutb
case = 276
 control = 193

For secondary trait (low workingmemory) with resampling from the primary participants; 
cases (low working memory) = 289
control (good working memory) =180

please ask me if any more informations are needed.